# Xamarin.iOS Native Crash Error SIGSEGV when registering for push notifications with hub in Azure

Tags: azure, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

I am using this method in the iOS project of my Xamarin app project to register with a notification hub in Azure for development (Hub and app are configured for development with certificates and provisioning on the apple developer portal, key word in entitlements.plist set to dev, hub has a p12 dev certificate uploaded).

This method (and hence the app) works perfectly fine on my iPhone 5S in dev mode.

But on my iPhone 8 Plus I get this error:

```
=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================
    0x103ef09c8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/10179C87-9D6C-4E2B-90AD- 
    57BF86C9C934/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS : (null)
    0x103ee67b0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/10179C87-9D6C-4E2B-90AD- 
    57BF86C9C934/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS : (null)
    0x103ef4ff0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/10179C87-9D6C-4E2B-90AD- 
    57BF86C9C934/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS : mono_pmip
    0x195cdf894 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : <redacted>
    0x10214029c - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Applica
    tion/10179C87-9D6C-4E2B-90AD-57BF86C9C934/ShakeAlarmRR1.iOS.app/ShakeAlarmRR1.iOS : (null)
    0x1021403fc - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/10179C87-9D6C-4E2B-90AD- 
    57BF86C9C934/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS : (null)
    0x102147ff8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/10179C87-9D6C-4E2B-90AD- 
    57BF86C9C934/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS : (null)
    0x102147b38 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/10179C87-9D6C-4E2B-90AD- 
    57BF86C9C934/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS : (null)
    0x102146364 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/10179C87-9D6C-4E2B-90AD- 
    57BF86C9C934/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS : (null)
    0x102145768 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/10179C87-9D6C-4E2B-90AD- 
    57BF86C9C934/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS : (null)
    0x102144620 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/10179C87-9D6C-4E2B-90AD- 
    57BF86C9C934/myapp.iOS.app/myapp.iOS : (null)
    0x1963b90b0 - /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation : <redacted>
    0x195ced1ec - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib : _pthread_start
    0x195cf0aec - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib : thread_start

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x195cdef44):0x195cdef34  c0 03 5f d6 1f 20 03 d5 1f 20 03 
d5 01 ec 7c 92  .._.. ... ....|.
0x195cdef44  20 00 c0 3d c3 f9 ff 10 62 04 c1 3c 02 0c 40 92   ..
=....b..<..@.
0x195cdef54  63 00 02 cb 61 00 c0 3d 00 1c a1 4e 05 00 00 14  c...a..=...N....
0x195cdef64  1f 20 03 d5 1f 20 03 d5 1f 20 03 d5 20 0c c1 3c  . ... ... .. ..<
```

In AppDelegate.cs:

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(
            UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
            AzureNotifHub = new SBNotificationHub(AppConstants.AZURE_DEVNOTIFHUB3_LISTENSHARED, 
  AppConstants.DEV_NOTIFHUB3);

            // update registration with Azure Notification Hub
            AzureNotifHub.UnregisterAllAsync(deviceToken, (error) =>
            {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to call unregister {error}");
                    return;
                }

                var tags = new NSSet(AppConstants.IOSSUBSCRIPTIONTAGS.ToArray());
                AzureNotifHub.RegisterNativeAsync(deviceToken, tags, (errorCallback) =>
                {
                    if (errorCallback != null)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine($"RegisterNativeAsync error: {errorCallback}");
                    }
                });

                var templateExpiration = 
 DateTime.Now.AddDays(120).ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en- 
 US"));
                AzureNotifHub.RegisterTemplateAsync(deviceToken, "defaultTemplate", 
 AppConstants.IOS_APNS_TEMPLATE_BODY, templateExpiration, tags, (errorCallback) =>
                {
                    if (errorCallback != null)
                    {
                        if (errorCallback != null)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine($"RegisterTemplateAsync error: {errorCallback}");
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

I am using the iPhone 8 Plus in development mode now. This device had the app downloaded from app store and hence previously registered with the notification hub in production mode, dont know if this has something to do with it.

Also I am using a BETA ios 13 OS.

What could cause this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Does it not work only in iOS 13?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT The iPhone 8 Plus is the only test device that I have that supports iOS 13, that is a good point you make. I have only tested with 12.4.1 on my iPhone 5S test device and it works.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be because of [this](https://twitter.com/_inside/status/1138478471590633473?s=20)

> NSData.description has changed when linking against iOS13/Catalina, so if you rely on that to generate a string version of your push token, you’re gonna have some issues

[You need to](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-ios/issues/30) have the latest version of the NotificationHub package. If that isn't fixed in the Xamarin version of the iOS package, you will have to create an issue on their Github